# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class FlowLayout

Tags: android, smali

I've this problem with a Launcher3 customization method, resulting in an error inflating FlowLayout.

*Edit*: **Full** Stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8596): Process: com.android.launcher3, PID: 8596
E/AndroidRuntime( 8596): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class FlowLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at com.android.launcher3.customizations.WallpaperCard.getContentView(WallpaperCard.java:166)
    at com.android.launcher3.customizations.BaseCustomizationCard.(BaseCustomizationCard.java:70)
    at com.android.launcher3.customizations.BaseCustomizationCard.(BaseCustomizationCard.java:53)
    at com.android.launcher3.customizations.WallpaperCard.(WallpaperCard.java:108)
    at com.android.launcher3.customizations.WallpaperPager$WallpaperPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(WallpaperPager.java:117)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1020)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2618)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1177)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.FlowLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.launcher3-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    ... 69 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.FlowLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 75 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

*Edit*: Seems it can't find the "android.view.FlowLayout" class. I think the problem is in this method, getContentView:

```
.method protected getContentView()Landroid/view/View;
    .locals 3

    .prologue
    .line 165
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/android/launcher3/customizations/WallpaperCard;->getContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v1}, Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->from(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 166
    .local v0, "layoutInflater":Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;
    const v1, 0x7f040028

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2}, Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->inflate(ILandroid/view/ViewGroup;)Landroid/view/View;

    move-result-object v1

    iput-object v1, p0, Lcom/android/launcher3/customizations/WallpaperCard;->mContent:Landroid/view/View;

    .line 167
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/android/launcher3/customizations/WallpaperCard;->mContent:Landroid/view/View;

    invoke-direct {p0, v1}, Lcom/android/launcher3/customizations/WallpaperCard;->setupContentView(Landroid/view/View;)V

    .line 168
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/android/launcher3/customizations/WallpaperCard;->reloadCustomizationSettings()V

    .line 169
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/android/launcher3/customizations/WallpaperCard;->mContent:Landroid/view/View;

    return-object v1
.end method
```

I'm starting with Smali, and I've no idea why this happens, nor **why it mentions a XML file**. (If someone's able to explain the reference to the XML I'll probably be able to find out why it happens)
Any help on how to fix it is much appreciated.

Comment: There is more to that stacktrace. There should be the words "Caused by"

Comment: Exactly @cricket_007, I was looking for that too, but that's the complete stacktrace (copied from adb logcat output).  It's not the first bug of this kind I've already solved, however not having a "Caused By" made me think the problem was somehow of a different kind.

Comment: Are you sure that is the full output? It looks like that last line is cut off

Comment: Yep, I'm sure, @cricket_007, the adb logcat output was exactly like that.. I'm trying right now to restore a dropbox entry that should contain the full stacktrace, hope it's complete (if it is, will edit the question with the full stack trace).   
Edit: The full stacktrace is now included.

Comment: `FlowLayout` doesn't exist in the [`android.view`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) package, so that perfectly explains that error

Comment: Fair enough. Any recommendations on how to fix it? Any substitute for FlowLayout? I've no idea why OnePlus did include that...

Comment: I'm not sure what, how, or where a reference to a FlowLayout class comes from, sorry.

Comment: FlowLayout is being used in a layout file that you're trying to inflate. The layout ID is 0x7f040028. Use this ID to find the name of the layout in R$layout.smali class. Then go to res/layout folder and find your layout file. It should contain FlowLayout - try to rename it to one of the Android's layouts (i.e. LinearLayout).